# how to forcefully send invalid url queries to 404 page - PHP

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I have custom 404 page and working fine for pages that does not exist.

But I also want to show 404 page if someone query_string found to be missing/invalid/null from url.

How can I do so?

```
www.example.com/mypage.php?param1=value1
if(isset($_GET['param1']) && $_GET['param1'] !='')
{
   //general code
}
else {
   // Here I want to redirect to 404.php
}
```

also my 404 page is being accessed directly, and I want to prevent it.

Comment: include 404 html inside the else and print it to browser (example)

Comment: Great idea. lemme try!

Comment: $url = 'YOUR_PAGE' // maybe YOUR_PAGE is page_404.php, 
header('Location: $url');

Comment: @Fahad you can use (example) include, include_once and do not really write all your html inside your page LOL ! for other create an error.php page and do redirect to it with htaccess for page that does not exist

Comment: @MarcoMura How to prevent direct access to 404 page. Including done it for missing/invalid params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using include, as Marco Mura suggested in his comment.

```
www.example.com/mypage.php?param1=value1
if(isset($_GET['param1']) && $_GET['param1'] !='')
{
   //general code
}
else {
   include "404.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect users to 404 page through `header()` function like this:

```
www.example.com/mypage.php?param1=value1
if(isset($_GET['param1']) && $_GET['param1'] !='')
{
   //general code
}
else {
   header('Location: http://www.example.com/404.php');
   exit;
}
```

Comment: Cant do this way. In fact I want to dis allow direct access to 404 page.

Comment: Then try to use `include('404.php');` in your else statement as Marco Mura suggested.

Comment: yup! done it, how to prevent direct access to 404.php ?

Comment: The best way to prevent direct access to files is to place them outside of the web-server document root (usually, one level above). You can still include them, but there is no possibility of someone accessing them through an http request.